# Problem with the splashscreen after resume ( Flutter - Android )

Tags: android, flutter

I've got a problem with my flutter app when I want to resume my app on android. So I tested the example flutter app that gets generated, but the problem also exists there. I modified only the launch_background.xml file to change the background color to black and put the launcher icon to the splash screen.

The problem is that when I resume the app after I paused it, the splash screen is visible for a short period of time. The gif below shows the problem.

Does anyone know a solution for this or do I have to deal with that?

Thanks in advance

[image: flutter android resume gif problem]

--EDIT--
Changes to the styles.xml in Android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: please show some that's done by you, so that it would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash). I use it in my all projects and it works flawlessly. Their doc says :

> Automatically generates native code for adding splash screens in Android and iOS. Customize with specific platform, background color and splash image.

Make sure to run the package with below line after you make all the changes :

```
flutter pub pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

Comment: Thanks it really works with that package that the app isn't flickering in onresume. After I checked the code the package generate it looks like the code that fixes my problem was the `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` in the `styles.xml`. But now the app is in fullscreen and the statusbar disappears. Found an example of him on github. Seems like I must clear the fullscreen flag after layout in the MainActivity. Maybe the code couldn't get generated from the library with kotlin files. Also the entry points seems different. I have `configureFlutterEngine` he has the `onCreate`.

Comment: you may want to see this link: https://github.com/henriquearthur/flutter_native_splash/issues/40

Comment: I ignored it a while now the problem seemed to be sovled. Looks like it was a problem with flutter itself. After switching the branch the problem doesn't occure anymore. Thanks a link in your link helped =]

Comment: Glad I could help.